# How to obtain the convolution of these functions?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, piecewise, algorithm, numerical-value

I am starting to use Mathematica. I wanted to compute
$$\nabla F*\phi(x),\;x\in\mathbb{R^2}$$
where $F(x)=\ln\|x\|$ and $\phi(x)=\chi_{B(0,2)}(x)$.

I am a new user of this software, so I don't know advanced commands yet. The code that I have used is:

```
F[x_, y_] = 1/2*Log[x^2 + y^2];
g[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= r}, {0, True}}]
C[z1_, z2_] = Convolve[Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}], g[x, y]
```

The problem is that this doesn't return any value after two hours of computation. Could someone tell me how can I solve this?

**EDIT**: I add some information about what I want to do, expecting that this can help to get a way to make this convolution.

After that I will need to compute the integral of the product of $C$ and certain function. Concretely, I want to compute the following line integral over the border of the disk $D(0,2)$

$$\int_{C(0,2)}F*g(x)\nabla F *g(x)\cdot n(x), $$
where $n$ denotes the normal vector.
The only way that I know to compute this is:

```
    F[x_, y_] = 1/2*Log[x^2 + y^2];
    g[x_, y_] = Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= r}, {0, True}}]
    C[z1_, z2_] = Convolve[Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}], g[x, y]
    C1[z1_, z2_] = Convolve[F[x, y], g[x, y], {x, y}, {z1, z2}]
    NIntegrate[ C1[r*Cos[s], r*Sin[s]]* Dot[C[r*Cos[s], r*Sin[s]], {r*Cos[s], r*Sin[s]}]  , {s, 0, 2*Pi}]
```

Comment: A big edit to the question should be described.

Comment: Sorry, it is my first question here. I hope it is better now

Comment: Please, indicate the substantial  change you made in the question.

Comment: Done! Sorry. I  hope this helps to get an answer to my question

Comment: 1. The functions  $w,n$ and the integral $$\int_{C(0,2)}F*w(x)\nabla F *w(x)\cdot n(x) $$ are not defined. 2. Ask a separate question instead of your edit.

Comment: There was some typos. The function $w$ is $g$. I think that the edit is better than ask a separate question because this gives information about what I want to do and it can helps to know the better way of computing the convolution

Comment: Crossposted [here](https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/2481487).

Answer (score 0):

First, the convolution is defined for functions, but `Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}]` is a vector. Second,

```
F[x_, y_] := 1/2*Log[x^2 + y^2];
g[x_, y_,r_] := Piecewise[{{1, x^2 + y^2 <= r}, {0, True}}];
Convolve[Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}][[1]], g[x, y,r], {x, y}, {z1, z2}, 
Assumptions -> r > 0]
```

returns the input. Therefore, the convolution should be realized numerically, making use of its definition:

```
c[r_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}][[1]]*g[x - z1, y - z2,r], {x, -Infinity, 
Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity},AccuracyGoal -> 4, PrecisionGoal -> 4, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
c[2, 2, -1]
```

> 2.2144

I leave the second coordinate of the gradient on your own.

Addition.

```
c[r_?NumericQ, z1_?NumericQ, z2_?NumericQ] := 
NIntegrate[(Evaluate[Grad[F[x, y], {x, y}]][[1]])*
g[x - z1, y - z2, r], {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
c[2, 2, -1]
```

> 2.51328

We see `NIntegrate` leaves much to be desired.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I understand the convolution of a vector and a a function as: $(F_1,F_2)*f=(F_1*f,F_2*f)$. I edit the question to clarify what I want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer BTW.  I'm not sure I understood your answer correctly, so there is no way to calculate this convolution?

Comment: `x^2 + y^2 <= r` should be `x^2 + y^2 <= r^2`. `g[x - z1, y - z2]` should be `g[x - z1, y - z2,r]`.

Comment: @cvgmt: Thank you. I followed the notation of the question. The typo in `g` is fixed.